# How can I find out the href that was used to call my controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

From inside a controller action I would like to get the full href address that was clicked on to get me to the action.

Is this possible and if so then how can I get that in MVC?

Comment: So for example if my controller is "about" and action is "home" then I need to be able to get the href that looks like href:/xxx.com/about/home

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) property of the current request:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

This will read the [Referer](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36) HTTP header from the request which may or may not be supplied by the client (user agent).

Comment: Sorry. I mean how can I find out the Href of that action?

Comment: Please explain (use an example if needed)

Comment: It's the same as I said before, Request.UrlReferrer

Comment: Like Ofer said, it's gonna be in the UrlReferrer if the client provided it.

Answer (score 0):

If a user clicks on a link, say `<a href='[url_here]'>Link</a>` that routes to your controller and action, you can get the url of [url_here] inside the action method by calling Request.Url.ToString().

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said about the Request.UrlReferrer you could also pass it as query string parameter:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "foo", new { url = Request.RawUrl })
```

and inside the action:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string url)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string fullPath = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```